# Force Binding isn't what I want

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

My oneway binding isn't working as I'm expecting.

When I click a button to add a new "person" it doesn't add the newly entered person to the listview until I shut it down and restart the application (so the value gets added to the DB just not to the UI)

What am I doing incorrectly?  I have the INotifyPropertyChanged, I have the ObservableCollection...  What am I missing?

I have my Model:

```
    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _personName;
        private string _personEmail;
        private string _personPhone;
        private DateTime _personDOB;

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int personId { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(25)]
        public string personName {
            get { return _personName; }
            set
            {
                _personName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("personName");
            }
        }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string personEmail { 
            get { return _personEmail; } 
            set
            {
                _personEmail = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("personEmail");
            } 
        }

        [MaxLength(13)]
        public string personPhone { 
            get { return _personPhone; } 
            set
            {
                _personPhone = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("personPhone");
            } 
        }
        public DateTime personDOB {
            get { return _personDOB;}
            set 
            { 
                _personDOB = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("personDOB");
            }
        }
        public Boolean isPersonActive { get; set; }

        public string Summary
        {
            get { return string.Format("{0} - {1} : {2} -- {3}", personName, personEmail, personPhone, personDOB); }
        }

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

In my ViewModel I have this:

```
public class ChoresVM
{
    private ObservableCollection<win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Person> _personList;
    public ObservableCollection<win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Person> personList
    {
        get { return _personList; }
        set { _personList = value; }
    }
```

...

```
    public ObservableCollection<win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Person> selectAllPerson()
    {
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            ObservableCollection<win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Person> pList = new ObservableCollection<win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Person>(db.Query<win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Person>("select personId,personName,personEmail,personDOB from Person"));
            _personList = new ObservableCollection<Model.databaseTables.Person>(db.Query<win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Person>("select personId,personName,personEmail,personDOB from Person"));
            return _personList;
        }
    }

    public void insertPerson(string name, string email, string phone, DateTime dob, Boolean isActive = true)
    {
        dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "myDB");
        db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
        using (db)
        {
            var p = db.Insert(new win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Person()
            {
                personName = name,
                personEmail = email,
                personPhone = phone,
                personDOB = dob,
                isPersonActive = isActive

            });
        }
        selectAllPerson();
    }
```

Then in my View:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        VM = new ViewModel.ChoresVM();
        DataContext = VM;
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime myDOB = new DateTime(1955, 02, 28);
        VM.insertPerson("test","test@live.com","123-456-7890", myDOB);
    }
```

With my XAML like this:

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="287,344,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="740" x:Name="test" DisplayMemberPath="Summary" ItemsSource="{Binding personList,  Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on ChoresVM and raise PropertyChanged("personList") when you initialize the collection (in selectAllPerson() or personList setter). This way itemssource binding will be notified, that collection property was changed and will pickup new collection. Also you have a typo. In Binding you have "PersonList" (Pascal case) but you property is in camel case (personList)

Comment: So I think the original error was the "PersonList" being cased wrong.  When I fixed that I no longer have to set the itemssource.  However, I updated my question further to address the Add button.  Any ideas?

Comment: When you insert new person you call selectAllPerson() which reinitialize personList property. Again, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChange and raise OnPropertyChanged("personList").